# Issues trying to SSH into a fresh EC2 instance with Paramiko

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, paramiko, boto

I'm working on a script that spins up a fresh EC2 instance with boto and uses the Paramiko SSH client to execute remote commands on the instance. For whatever reason, the Paramiko client is unabled to connect, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/sconfigure.py", line 29, in <module>
    ssh.connect(instance.ip_address, username='ubuntu', key_filename=os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/test'))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 291, in connect
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I can ssh in fine manually using the same key file and user. Has anyone run into issues using Paramiko? My full code is below. Thanks.

```
import boto.ec2, time, paramiko, os
# Connect to the us-west-1 region
ec2 = boto.ec2.regions()[3].connect()
image_id = 'ami-ad7e2ee8'
image_name = 'Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) 32-bit EBS'
new_reservation = ec2.run_instances(
    image_id=image_id,
    key_name='test',
    security_groups=['web'])

instance = new_reservation.instances[0]

print "Spinning up instance for '%s' - %s. Waiting for it to boot up." % (image_id, image_name)
while instance.state != 'running':
    print "."
    time.sleep(1)
    instance.update()

print "Instance is running, ip: %s" % instance.ip_address

print "Connecting to %s as user %s" % (instance.ip_address, 'ubuntu')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(instance.ip_address, username='ubuntu', key_filename=os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/test'))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo "TEST"')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: +1 good question! I've never done anything with my EC2 account, this will give me some impetus.

Comment: have you tried specifying the port as the 2nd parameter in ssh.connect()?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have. I believe I have figured it out though. Even though the instance status is "running" according to boto, there seems to be a delay for when it will actually accept any SSH connections. Adding a time.slep(25) before trying to make the connection seems to be enough, but I'm going to do some more testing.

Comment: great! once you get it working perhaps you could answer your own question so it's there for the next guy who runs into this!

Comment: exactly. doing time.sleep(60) will solve the problem. But your code inspires me about the paramiko part. thanks dude.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I seem to have figured this out by trial and error. Even though the instance status is "running" according to boto, there is a delay for when it will actually allow an SSH connection. Adding a "time.sleep(30)" before the "ssh.connect(...)" seems to do the trick for me, though this may vary.

Comment: Probably 'running' means that the image itself is booting? So you have to wait for the OS to start, and sshd to start.

Comment: Yea, that makes the most sense.

Comment: I do the same as you (with 45 seconds :p) and that's the only way I found to do it even if I dislike to do a sleep(x)

Comment: you dont need to do this. you can try to connect for a number of times and catch the exceptions. I successfully implemented [this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2560472/573216) to work with paramiko.

Comment: Jeez that was frustrating! Thank you @rr. !! I'm using boto's `sshclient_from_instance` which relies on paramiko, obviously. I just think this is not a good error message and API design. It just shouldn't be as mysterious - unless this use case is rare, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The way to check it's ssh available is to make sure its two status checks both passes. On web UI it looks like this:
[image]

And using boto3 (the original question used boto but it was 5 years ago), we can do:

```
session = boto3.Session(...)
client = session.client('ec2')
res = client.run_instances(...) # launch instance
instance_id = res['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']

while True:
    statuses = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    status = statuses['InstanceStatuses'][0]
    if status['InstanceStatus']['Status'] == 'ok' \
            and status['SystemStatus']['Status'] == 'ok':
        break
    print '.'
    time.sleep(5)
print "Instance is running, you are ready to ssh to it"
```

Comment: This works, I tried it.  One note: you can ssh to nodes before both of these statuses switch from 'initializing' to 'ok'.  So if your code is impatient and wants to ssh as very soon as possible, a different technique may be better.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `boto.manage.cmdshell` instead?

```
cmd = boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                                   key_path,
                                                   user_name='ec2_user')
```

(code taken from line 152 in [ec2_launch_instance.py](https://github.com/garnaat/paws/blob/master/ec2_launch_instance.py))

For available `cmdshell` commands have a look at the `SSHClient` class from [cmdshell.py](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/manage/cmdshell.py).

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue. The "correct" way would be to initiate a close() first and then reopen the connection. However on older versions, close() was broken.

With this version or later, it should be fixed:
https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/412

"Proper" method:

```
newinstance = image.run(min_count=instancenum, max_count=instancenum, key_name=keypair, security_groups=security_group, user_data=instancename, instance_type=instancetype, placement=zone)
time.sleep(2)
newinstance.instances[0].add_tag('Name',instancename)

print "Waiting for public_dns_name..."
counter = 0
while counter < 70:
    time.sleep(1)
    conn.close()
    conn = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(ec2auth.access_key,ec2auth.private_key)
    startedinstance = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=str(newinstance.instances[0].id))[0]
    counter = counter + 1
    if str(startedinstance.instances[0].state) == "running":
        break
    if counter == 69:
        print "Timed out waiting for instance to start."
print "Added: " + startedinstance.instances[0].tags['Name'] + " " + startedinstance.instances[0].public_dns_name
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating a new connection each time through the loop.  This code (https://github.com/garnaat/paws/blob/master/ec2_launch_instance.py) does a similar loop using the same connection each time through.  I've never had a problem with that pattern.

Comment: The problem is, the initial connection is cached. So it won't recheck for an update unless you close and reopen the connection. This is what I've found in my testing though. Haven't talked to the boto guys about it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently view this code and I have a suggestion for code,
Instead of running while loop to check whether the instance is running or not, you can try "wait_until_running()".

Following is the sample code...

```
client = boto3.resource(
    'ec2',
    region_name="us-east-1"
)

Instance_ID = "<your Instance_ID>"
instance = client.Instance(Instance_ID)
instance.start()
instance.wait_until_running()
```

After that try to code for the ssh connection code.