# How to use boto.manage.cmdshell with ssh-agent?

Tags: python, ssh, boto, paramiko

I'm using `boto.manage.cmdshell` to create an SSH connection to EC2 instances. Currently every time the user has to enter its password to encrypt the pkey (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`).

Now I want to make the work-flow more convenient for the users and support `ssh-agent`.
So far I tried without any success:

- set `ssh_key_file` to `None` when creating `FakeServer`:

  The result was: `SSHException('Key object may not be empty')`
- set `ssh_pwd` to `None` when creating `SSHClient`:

  The result was: `paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted`

Is there a way to use `ssh-agent` with `boto.manage.cmdshell`? I know that `paramiko` supports it, which boto is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by creating a class `SSHClientAgent` which inherited from `boto.manage.cmdshell.SSHClient` and overwrites the `__init__()`. In the new `__init__()` I replaced the call to `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file()` with `None`.

Here is my new class:

```
class SSHClientAgent(boto.manage.cmdshell.SSHClient):

    def __init__(self, server,
                 host_key_file='~/.ssh/known_hosts',
                 uname='root', timeout=None, ssh_pwd=None):
        self.server = server
        self.host_key_file = host_key_file
        self.uname = uname
        self._timeout = timeout
        # replace the call to get the private key
        self._pkey = None
        self._ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self._ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
        self._ssh_client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(host_key_file))
        self._ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.connect()
```

In my function where I create the ssh connection I check for the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and decide which ssh client to create.

Answer (score 1):

(There's another stackoverflow page with some related answers)
[Can't get amazon cmd shell to work through boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370463/cant-get-amazon-cmd-shell-to-work-through-boto)

However, you're definitely better using per-person SSH keys.  But if you have those, are they in the target host's authorized_keys file?  If so, users just add their key normally with ssh-add (in an ssh-agent session, usually the default in Linux). You need to test with ssh itself first, so that ssh-agent/-add issues are clearly resolved beforehand.

Once certain they work with ssh normally, the problem is whether boto thought ssh-agent at all.  Paramiko's SSHClient() can, if I remember correctly - the paramiko code I remember looks roughly like:

```
paramiko.SSHClient().connect(host, timeout=10, username=user,
                             key_filename=seckey, compress=True)
```

The seckey was optional, so the key_filename would be empty, and that invoked checking the ssh-agent.  Boto's version seems to want to force using a private key file with an explicit call like this, I think with the idea that each instance will have an assigned key and password to decrypt it:

```
  self._pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(server.ssh_key_file,
                                                     password=ssh_pwd)
```

If so, it means that using boto directly conflicts with using ssh-agent and the standard model of per-user logins and logging of connections by user.

The paramiko.SSHClient() is much more capable, and documents ssh-agent support explicitly (from pydoc paramiko.SSHClient):

```
  Authentication is attempted in the following order of priority:
      - The C{pkey} or C{key_filename} passed in (if any)
      - Any key we can find through an SSH agent
      - Any "id_rsa" or "id_dsa" key discoverable in C{~/.ssh/}
      - Plain username/password auth, if a password was given
```

Basically, you'd *have* to use paramiko instead of boto.

We had one issue with paramiko: The connection would *not* be ready immediately in many cases, requiring sending a test command through and checkout output before sending real commands.  Part of this was that we'd start firing off SSH commands (with paramiko) *right* after creating and EC2 or VPC instance, so there was no guarantee it'd be listening for an SSH connect, and paramiko would tend to lose commands delivered too soon.  We used some code like this to cope:

```
def SshCommand(**kwargs):
    '''
    Run a command on a remote host via SSH.

    Connect to the given host=<host-or-ip>, as user=<user> (defaulting to
    $USER), with optional seckey=<secret-key-file>, timeout=<seconds>
    (default 10), and execute a single command=<command> (assumed to be
    addressing a unix shell at the far end.

    Returns the exit status of the remote command (otherwise would be
    None save that an exception should be raised instead).

    Example: SshCommand(host=host, user=user, command=command, timeout=timeout,
                        seckey=seckey)
    '''
    remote_exit_status = None

    if debug:
        sys.stderr.write('SshCommand kwargs: %r\n' % (kwargs,))

    paranoid = True

    host = kwargs['host']
    user = kwargs['user'] if kwargs['user'] else os.environ['USER']
    seckey = kwargs['seckey']
    timeout = kwargs['timeout']
    command = kwargs['command']

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    time_end = time.time() + int(timeout)

    ssh_is_up = False
    while time.time() < time_end:
        try:
            ssh.connect(host, timeout=10, username=user, key_filename=seckey,
                        compress=True)
            if paranoid:
                token_generator = 'echo xyz | tr a-z A-Z'
                token_result = 'XYZ'      # possibly buried in other text
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(token_generator)
                lines = ''.join(stdout.readlines())
                if re.search(token_result, lines):
                    ssh_is_up = True
                    if debug:
                        sys.stderr.write("[%d] command stream is UP!\n"
                                         % time.time())
                    break
            else:
                ssh_is_up = True
                break
        except paramiko.PasswordRequiredException as e:
            sys.stderr.write("usage idiom clash: %r\n" % (e,))
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            sys.stderr.write("[%d] command stream not yet available\n"
                             % time.time())
            if debug:
                sys.stderr.write("exception is %r\n" % (e,))
        time.sleep(1)

    if ssh_is_up:
        # ideally this is where Bcfg2 or Chef or such ilk get called.
#       stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        chan = ssh._transport.open_session()
        chan.exec_command(command)
        # note that out/err doesn't have inter-stream ordering locked down.
        stdout = chan.makefile('rb', -1)
        stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('rb', -1)
        sys.stdout.write(''.join(stdout.readlines()))
        sys.stderr.write(''.join(stderr.readlines()))
        remote_exit_status = chan.recv_exit_status()
        if debug:
            sys.stderr.write('exit status was: %d\n' % remote_exit_status)

    ssh.close()
    if None == remote_exit_status:
        raise SSHException('remote command result undefined')
    return remote_exit_status
```

We were also trying to enforce not logging into prod directly, so this particular wrapper (an ssh-send-command script) encourage scripting despite the vagaries of whether Amazon had bothered to start the instance in a timely fashion.

Comment: Good solution and I really like the advice about the problem that the connection is maybe not ready. I'll incorporate that in my program. But I found a different solution and I'll go with that, which I posted.

Comment: Deriving to *override* the __init__ is really clever in this case.  Folding the shell-really-there test as well would be a great next step.