# (urllib.urlretrieve not working)IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, file-transfer, data-transfer

My problem is that i use
python2

```
>> import urllib
>> urllib.urlretrieve ("https://IP/myFile.txt", "myFile.txt")
```

Obviously, this file exists on the other end, but from my machine, all I get is IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused.

I don't have a VPN up, just an antivirus. My machine is an Ubuntu on a VM and the target machine, is just a machine from HTB(an academy class).

Also, used python3

```
>> import urllib.request
>> urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://IP/myFile.txt", "myFile.txt")
```

Also, I want to upload a file (trying out scp). It says "1 file copied", but there is no file copied to the target machine, sadly.

For reference, it's an academy module. What am I doing wrong? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I/O error(socket error): \[Errno 111\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558801/i-o-errorsocket-error-errno-111-connection-refused)

Comment: @Beefster it helped. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Since this hasn't officially been marked as a duplicate yet, it would be kind to post your solution. Nothing is worse than coming across "I fixed it" with no additional information when trying to solve a problem.